# Запрет на использование геттеров и сеттеров в дочерних классах

Tags: php, ооп, наследование, инкапсуляция

Есть следующий класс с приватными полями и публичными геттерами и сеттерами:

```
class Market extends Scope
{
    protected $id;
    private $source_type;
    private $is_active;
    private $manual_settled;

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    final public function getSourceType()
    {
        return $this->source_type;
    }

    public final function setSourceType($source_type): void
    {
        $this->source_type = $source_type;
    }

    final public function getIsActive(): bool
    {
        return $this->is_active;
    }

    final public function setIsActive(bool $is_active): void
    {
        $this->is_active = $is_active;
    }

    public function getManualSettled()
    {
        return $this->manual_settled;
    }

    public function setManualSettled($manual_settled): void
    {
        $this->manual_settled = $manual_settled;
    }
}
```

От этого класса наследуется другой класс (пока что пустой):

```
class Outcome extends Market
{

}
```

Как запретить дочернему классу ВЫЗЫВАТЬ (не перегружать, про final знаю) геттеры и сеттеры для приватных полей?

Comment: сделать их приватными :). Объясните, какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить таким способом.

Comment: У меня должно быть 3 класса: Scope (type), Market (id, source_type, is_active, manual_settled, type(наследую у Scope)), Outcome (id, type). Я сделал наследование: Scope->Market->Outcome (в файле XML, который нужно распарсить именно такая вложенность).

Comment: Унаследованным классам ни как не запретить пользоваться методами родителя

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Я сделал наследование: Scope->Market->Outcome (в файле XML, который
>   нужно распарсить именно такая вложенность)

Наследование (как принцип или инструмент) абсолютно не соответствует вложенности данных в XML.

Вам нужна агрегация/владение - один класс содержит объект[ы] другого класса.

Answer (score 2):

На то он и наследник, чтобы унаследовать всё, что вы объявляете public или protected. Посмотрите в сторону [паттерна "Делегирование"](https://refactoring.guru/ru/replace-inheritance-with-delegation)